# Android layoutdisplay ,layout over layout.

Tags: android, image, android-layout, layout

[image]

As showing on the picture. I want to display the star image above layout .
I am new to this type of coding .

my query is 
1)will It possible to display star(image) on my layout side?

2)If on every click on my event I want to display star like and display like second image will it possible?
Means on same screen I have to save the star with their respect position .

[image]
thanks in Advanced?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
     private RelativeLayout _mainLayout;

     /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.canvas);
       _mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
                 ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
                 image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                 layoutParams.leftMargin = X - bitmap.getWidth()/2;
                 layoutParams.topMargin = Y - bitmap.getHeight()/2;
                 layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                 layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                 image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                 _mainLayout.addView(image);
                 break;
           }
           return false;
      }
 }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/canvas"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/bg0large"
        >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thnk you,,,
may be its work for me..
I have one doubt. Will I display one image on another image>?

Answer (score 0):

To do layout over layout, you should to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: It should be comment rather than answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display one layout over another layout you should use FrameLayout
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html